# Why do I keep getting an attribute error for this method in a class?

Tags: python, methods, tree, attributes

I am trying to create a decision tree.  I keep getting the error
'DecisionTree' object has no attribute 'gini' (and whatever other function I put in there).  Example:

```
class DecisionTree():
        def __init__(self, data, features, rows, min_samples_split =2, max_depth = 5, depth = None, **kwargs): 
            self.data = data  
            self.features = list(self.data.columns)
            self.rows = data.index
            self.min_samples_split = min_samples_split
            self.max_depth = max_depth
            self.depth = depth
            self.counts = Counter()
            self.root = None
            self.child = None
    
        def gini(self):
            t = len(self.data)
            p = self.data.groupby(self.features).size()/t
            return 1 - sum(p **2)

tree1 = DecisionTree(df, features, rows)

tree1.gini()
        Attribute error 'DecisionTree' object has no attribute
```

'gini'

Comment: What is `tree1`? How is it initialized?

Comment: what is `tree1`? If I do `tree1 = DecisionTree()`, I do not get this error. Please **always** provide a [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure `def gini` is inside the `class DecisionTree`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The error message says that `tree1` is a `DecisionTree` object. So the problem seems like it must be with the way the class is defined.

Comment: @Barmar yes, or, the OP defined the class multiple times in something like a Jupyter Notebook and then tried to call a method on an instance that was created from a previous class. In **any case** a [mcve] is required, or else we are just going to sit around and speculate about all the many possible reasons this could happen

Comment: It looks to me like `def gini` is indented one less space than `def __init__`. This would cause your `AttributeError`.

Comment: @user99999 That would cause an indentation error and none of the rest of the code would run.